# JQuery cycle plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I am trying to add jquery Cycle slideshow plugin to my page with 'fade' transition effect. But still I couldn't make it to work.

This is my html :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slide1">
         <blockquote>
            <span class="leftquotes">&ldquo;</span> He promptly completed the task at hand and communicates really well till the project reaches the finishing line. I was pleased with his creative design and will definitely be hiring him again. <span class="rightquotes">&bdquo; </span>
         </blockquote>
         <img src="images/profile.jpg" width="120" height="100" />
         <h2>Steve Kruger</h2>
         <h6>UI/UX Designer at Woof Design Studio</h6>
         <div class="slide1bottom"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide2">
        <blockquote>
            <span class="leftquotes">&ldquo;</span> Till the project reaches the finishing line. I recommend him to anyone who wants their work done professionally. project reaches the finishing line. I recommend him to anyone who wants their work done professionally. The project ... <a href="#"> read more</a><span class="rightquotes">&bdquo; </span>
        </blockquote>
        <img src="images/images.jpg" width="120" height="100" />
        <h2>John Doe</h2>
        <h6>Developer Relations at Woof Studios</h6>
        <div class="slide2bottom"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide3">
        <blockquote>
            <span class="leftquotes "> &ldquo;</span> He promptly completed the task at hand and communicates really well till the project reaches the finishing line. I was pleased with his creative design and will definitely be hiring him again. <span class="rightquotes">&bdquo; </span>
        </blockquote>
        <img src="images/summer_school.png" width="120" height="100" />
        <h2>Steve Stevenson</h2>
        <h6>CEO Woof Web Design Studios</h6>
        <div class="slide3bottom"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is my JQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').cycle();
});
```

I have imported JQuery plugin, cycle plugin and easing plugin to my page properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.color.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

This is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kRZ5r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you have specified for initializing `cycle` is looking for an `id` when it should be looking for a `class`.

```
$('.container').cycle({
   timeout: 10000
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kRZ5r/2/)

Comment: Oops, Big mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Use `timeout` setting. Options for original cycle can be found here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html and Cycle2 options are found here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/api/ @TNK

Answer (score 1):

You have this markup:

```
<div class="container">
```

Yet you use this selector:

```
$('#container').cycle();
```

`#` is used for `id` selectors, You would need to use `.`, which is the `class` selector:

```
$('.container').cycle();
```

It's also worth noting that Mr. Alsup has released a shiny new update, **Cycle2** (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/), that is HTML5 compatible and can leverage `data-` attributes for automagic initialization.

Answer (score 1):

In the html code you mention a container as a class. but in the JQuery you use # to define it as a id.

```
<div class="container">
</div>

$(function() {
    $('.container').cycle();
});
```